# Adding ACL to Hyperledger Composer Query

Tags: acl, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

According to the [hyperledger ACL documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/acl_language) and [ACL trading tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/acl-trading), ACL's can be used to add user access restrictions to certain assets and transactions within a hyperledger composer business network.

Can ACL's be implemented to restrict participant access to certain queries as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use ACLs to restrict the available pre-defined queries a participant can invoke, but ACL rules are applied to the results of queries allowing you to restrict what information is returned from a query for a specific participant, ie the list of assets returned by a query are processed by the ACL rules and only those that are ALLOWED are added to the results returned.